# Visual Studio 2015 bower not installing resources

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and getting an error when attempting to use bower to install resources.

Here is my bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "ASP.NET",
    "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.5",
    "angular-resource": "1.4.5",
    "angular-route": "1.4.5",
    "jQuery": "2.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5"
  }
}
```

Here is my output with the error:

```
bower angular#1.4.5         not-cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.5
bower angular#1.4.5            resolve https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.5
bower angular-resource#1.4.5       not-cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.4.5
bower angular-resource#1.4.5          resolve https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.4.5
bower angular-route#1.4.5          not-cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.4.5
bower angular-route#1.4.5             resolve https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.4.5
bower bootstrap#3.3.5              not-cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.5
bower bootstrap#3.3.5                 resolve https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.5
bower angular-resource#1.4.5         checkout v1.4.5
bower angular#1.4.5                  checkout v1.4.5
bower angular-route#1.4.5            checkout v1.4.5
bower bootstrap#3.3.5                checkout v3.3.5
bower angular-resource#1.4.5          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git -b v1.4.5 --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #-532462766
```

The directory for bower is setup to be wwwroot/lib.  I was told Visual Studio had a bug where it would say Bower did not install the resources but actually it did however I do not see the resources in the wwwroot/lib folder as they should, leaving me to believe this is not the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it :

- **Install** standalone Git from http://git-scm.com/
- **Open** bash and **execute** to use https instead on git (firewall maybe blocking git protocol) :

  `git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`
- now just **Configure** Visual studio to use this new git tool instead :

  [image]
  **add** the last line and **uncheck** the old git command line.

hope this helps